# Rest API to output in .json

Tags: python

I am creating a script that will call a rest API in python and spits out the results in `JSON` format. I am getting some few trace back errors in my code. How can I go about fixing this issue.

```
'import sitecustomize' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Desktop/Sync.py", line 12, in <module>
    url = urllib2.Request(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 202, in __init__
    self.__original = unwrap(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1057, in unwrap
    url = url.strip()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 229, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError, attr
AttributeError: strip
```

**Here's the code:**

```
import urllib2
import json
url = "http://google.com"
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header("Authorization","Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
socket = urllib2.urlopen(request)
data = json.dumps(socket)

hdrs = socket.headers
source = socket.read()
socket.close()

print "---- Headers -----"
print data
print "---- Source HTML -----"
print source
print "---- END -----"

value = 0
for line in source.splitlines():
    if not line.strip():  continue
    if line.startswith("value="):
        try:
            value = line.split("=")
        except IndexError:
            pass
    if value > 0:
        break

open("some.json", "w").write("value is: %d" % value)
```

Comment: Use `requests` instead of `urllib2` - you'll find it easier. Also, this looks like a problem with your python setup.

Comment: At least your `json.loads` works on nothing and it will fail.

Comment: Try removing `url = urllib2.Request(request)` and  replace the next line with `socket = urllib2.urlopen(request)`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an issue here:

```
request=urllib2.Request( "http.google.com")
request.add_header("Authorization","Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=")
url = urllib2.Request(request)
socket = urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

You are trying to create a Request object named "url" by passing a Request object into the constructor.

See http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request

Try this:

```
request=urllib2.Request( "http.google.com")
request.add_header("Authorization","Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=")
socket = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request) of `Request` class:

> url should be a string containing a valid URL.

You are curretnly passing another `Request` object to its constructor, so that's the reason for the error you're seeing. The correct way to do this:

```
request=urllib2.Request( "http.google.com")
request.add_header("Authorization","Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=")
socket = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Comment: I have eddited the above code and now its working. Had a few adjustments in naming and that helped out